# parse .xml with prefix's on tags? xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I can read tags, except when there is a prefix. I'm not having luck searching SO for a previous question.

I need to read `media:content`. I tried `image = node.find("media:content")`.
Rss input:

```
<channel>
  <title>Popular  Photography in the last 1 week</title>
  <item>
    <title>foo</title>
    <media:category label="Miscellaneous">photography/misc</media:category>
    <media:content url="http://foo.com/1.jpg" height="375" width="500" medium="image"/>
  </item>
  <item> ... </item>
</channel>
```

I can read a sibling tag `title`.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
with open('cache1.rss', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.findall('.//channel/item'):
    title =  node.find("title").text
```

*I've been using the docs, yet stuck on the 'prefix' part.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of using XML namespaces with *ElementTree*:

```
>>> x = '''\
<channel xmlns:media="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <title>Popular  Photography in the last 1 week</title>
  <item>
    <title>foo</title>
    <media:category label="Miscellaneous">photography/misc</media:category>
    <media:content url="http://foo.com/1.jpg" height="375" width="500" medium="image"/>
  </item>
  <item> ... </item>
</channel>
'''
>>> node = ElementTree.fromstring(x)
>>> for elem in node.findall('item/{http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/}category'):
        print elem.text


photography/misc
```

Answer (score 0):

`media` is an XML namespace, it has to be defined somewhere earlier with `xmlns:media="..."`. See http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes for how to define xml namespaces for use in XPath expressions in lxml.