# Searching an XML document for an element in a namespace

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

The following is my code:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get("http://www.volcano.si.edu/news/WeeklyVolcanoRSS.xml")
tree = ET.fromstring(r.text.encode('utf-8'))
for pt in tree.findall('.//georss:point'):
    print (pt.text)
```

The problem is that `:` is seen as a prefix error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 83, in xpath_tokenizer
raise SyntaxError("prefix %r not found in prefix map" % prefix)
SyntaxError: prefix 'georss' not found in prefix map
```

After adding a backslash to escape the character:

```
for pt in tree.findall('.//georss\:point'):
```

...it gives another error instead:

```
SyntaxError: prefix 'georss\\' not found in prefix map
```

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The colon in the XML tag is an XML namespace.

Check the source document for an attribute like `xmlns:georss="<URL>"`. The URL is your namespace.

See: [parse .xml with prefix's on tags? xml.etree.ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949092/parse-xml-with-prefixs-on-tags-xml-etree-elementtree)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the namespace by adding an argument to the `findall()` method. Try this:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get("http://www.volcano.si.edu/news/WeeklyVolcanoRSS.xml")
tree = ET.fromstring(r.text.encode('utf-8'))
namespaces = {'georss' : 'http://www.georss.org/georss'}
for pt in tree.findall('.//georss:point', namespaces=namespaces):
    print (pt.text)
```

Comment: This is not working with python 2.6. Is there any other way?